# Pandas read_table columns with multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a text file (ClassTest.txt) and pandas. The text file has 3, tab-separated columns: Title, Description, and Category - Title and Description are normal strings and Category is a (non-zero) integer.

I was gathering the data as follows:

```
data = pd.read_table('ClassTest.txt')

feature_names = ['Title', 'Description']
X = data[feature_names]
y = data['Category']
```

However, because values in the Description column can themselves contain new lines, the 'y' DataFrame contains too many rows because of most of the items in the Description column having multiple lines. I attempted to get around this by making the newline character in the file to be '|' (by repopulating it) and using:

```
data = pd.read_table('ClassTest.txt', lineterminator='|')
X = data[feature_names]
y = data['Category']
```

This time, I get the error:

`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 20, saw 5`

Can anyone help me with this issue?

EDIT: Adding previous code

```
con = lite.connect('JobDetails.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''SELECT Title, Description, Category FROM ReviewJobs''')

results = [list(each) for each in cur.fetchall()]

cur.execute('''SELECT Title, Description, Category FROM Jobs''')

for each in cur.fetchall():
    results.append(list(each))

a = open('ClassTest.txt', 'ab')

newLine = "|"

a.write(u''.join(c for c in 'Title\tDescription\tCategory' + newLine).encode('utf-8'))

for r in results:
    toWrite = "".encode('utf-8')
    title = u''.join(c for c in r[0].replace("\n", " ")).encode('utf-8') + "\t".encode('utf-8')
    description = u''.join(c for c in r[1]).encode('utf-8') + "\t".encode('utf-8')
    toWrite += title + description
    toWrite += str(r[2]).encode('utf-8') + newLine.encode('utf-8')
    a.write(toWrite)

a.close()
```

Comment: If your Dataset is big enough, you can just delete the rows throwing the error. We call that Data Cleaning xD

Comment: @MLAlex The error is coming while trying to create the DataFrame. Is it possible to remove before then?

Comment: Can you post your whole code? Try to delete row 20 of your source text file. If I'm not mistaken the error means that you try to put a data structure with 5 "parts" into a data structure which can only hold 3 parts.

Comment: @MLAlex, I have edited to add in the preceding code

Comment: Ahh I see.Try: data = pd.read_table('ClassTest.txt', error_bad_lines=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.read_table()` is deprecated – use `read_csv()` instead.  And then really use the CSV format instead of writing lots of code to write something similar that can't cope with record or field delimiters within fields.  There's the `csv` module in the Python standard library.

Opening the file as text file and passing the encoding to `open()` spares you from encoding everything yourself in different places.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from contextlib import closing
import csv
import sqlite3


def main():
    with sqlite3.connect("JobDetails.db") as connection:
        with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
            #
            # TODO Having two tables with the same columns for essentially
            #   the same kind of records smells like a broken DB design.
            #
            rows = list()
            for table_name in ["reviewjobs", "jobs"]:
                cursor.execute(
                    f"SELECT title, description, category FROM {table_name}"
                )
            rows.extend(cursor.fetchall())

    with open("ClassTest.txt", "a", encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter="\t")
        writer.write(["Title", "Description", "Category"])
        for title, description, category in rows:
            writer.writerows([title.replace("\n", " "), description, category])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the in the other program:

```
data = pd.read_csv("ClassTest.txt", delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this new solution. I have now set this as the best answer

Comment: (The two tables have some columns in common but not all because they are a different format)